# Endo/Exo for same length bridges

Tags: nomenclature, stereochemistry, pericyclic

I'm looking at a cycloaddition that produces a bicyclic intermediate, there are two different ways of doing the addition which can be described as *endo*/*exo*. However, all three bridges are the same length. How do I assign priorities and *endo*/*exo* here?

Here's a simplified example of this reaction. In my opinion on the dienophile the $\ce{NH2}$ has the higher priority, on the pyridazine I would suspect the $\ce{N-N}$ bridge to be higher in priority which means the left product would be *endo*, the right one *exo*. But I cannot find information that confirms this.

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge the endo/exo rules have as yet not been incorporated into the CIP system. Your idea has merit though. [Although your DA reaction is offered as an example, it is unlikely that the enamine tautomer of the dienophile would prevail over the imine.]

Comment: @user55119 well that would explain why I cannot find any information on this. And yes I know about the hypothetical tautomer and the product will eliminate N2 right away, but since I'm doing calculations everything is possible. ;-) That was just a very simple system with all the key features I needed.

Comment: *Endo/exo* stereodescriptors cannot be used for the preferred IUPAC names anyway.

Comment: @mykhal I need it to describe the configuration of the transition states and I don't see an easier way to do this.

Comment: IUPAC not withstanding, a CIP-like nomenclature could be developed. Just as E/Z covers all double bonds and cis/trans does not, endo/exo could be replaced with a more inclusive CIP system. E.g., your NH2 group has precedent over C6H5 while N=N has priority over C=C. Assuming the NH2 is bold in the first structure and dotted in the second, so your first DA adduct would be Z-ish and the second structure E-ish.  ;)

Comment: @user55119 that "Z-ish" and "E-ish" is exactly endo/exo...